# Query NearGeoPoint returning empty object

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to find users nearby the current logged user but somehow the result object isnt returning any user.

var currentUserGeoPoint = PFUser.currentUser()!["currentLocation"] as! PFGeoPoint

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"User")
    query.whereKey("currentLocation", nearGeoPoint: currentUserGeoPoint, withinKilometers: 100)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects, error) -> Void in
        if (error == nil) {
            println(objects)
        }else {
            println(error?.userInfo)
        }
}
```

Console return: `Optional([])`

This is my User Table:
[image]

As you can see my User class is set as public. (I know it is not best practice)
[image]

Comment: can you post a picture of your parse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class name should be _User.

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"_User")
    query.whereKey("currentLocation", nearGeoPoint: currentUserGeoPoint, withinKilometers: 100)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects, error) -> Void in
        if (error == nil) {
            println(objects)
        }else {
            println(error?.userInfo)
        }
}
```